# Visual Styles is not working in .NET 5.0 application after publishing

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, publish

When I publishing .NET 5.0 self-contained application with "*Produce single file*" option, some elements (buttons, checkboxes, comboboxes, etc.) start to look like they are in the Windows XP.

[image: bug]

I have searched on Google, but found nothing useful. (*updated: single file version of application uses **ComCtl32.dll** version **5.82** instead of **6.10***)

In all cases, `IsAppThemed()` and `IsThemeActive()` from uxtheme.dll returns true.

OS: *Windows 7 Ultimate x64, Service Pack 1*.

Confidential info replaced with ***.

Compiler command (same with enabled and disabled "*Produce Single File*"; every argument is on new line):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\csc.exe
/noconfig
/unsafe-
/checked-
/nowarn:1701,1702,1701,1702,2008
/fullpaths
/nostdlib+
/platform:x64
/errorreport:prompt
/warn:5
/define:TRACE;RELEASE;NET;NET5_0;NETCOREAPP;WINDOWS
/errorendlocation
/preferreduilang:en-US
/highentropyva+
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\Accessibility.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\Microsoft.CSharp.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\Microsoft.VisualBasic.Core.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\Microsoft.VisualBasic.Forms.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\Microsoft.Win32.Registry.AccessControl.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\mscorlib.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\netstandard.dll"
/reference:"C:\Users\Влади\.nuget\packages\pinvoke.kernel32\0.7.78\lib\netstandard2.0\PInvoke.Kernel32.dll"
/reference:"C:\Users\Влади\.nuget\packages\pinvoke.user32\0.7.78\lib\netstandard2.0\PInvoke.User32.dll"
/reference:"C:\Users\Влади\.nuget\packages\pinvoke.windows.core\0.7.78\lib\netstandard2.0\PInvoke.Windows.Core.dll"
/reference:"C:\Users\Влади\.nuget\packages\pinvoke.windows.shellscalingapi\0.7.78\lib\netstandard2.0\PInvoke.Windows.ShellScalingApi.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.AppContext.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Buffers.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.CodeDom.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Collections.Concurrent.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Collections.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Collections.Immutable.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Collections.NonGeneric.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Collections.Specialized.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.ComponentModel.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.ComponentModel.Primitives.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Configuration.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Console.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Core.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Data.Common.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Data.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Design.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Diagnostics.Contracts.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Diagnostics.EventLog.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Diagnostics.Process.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.DirectoryServices.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Drawing.Common.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Drawing.Design.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Drawing.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Drawing.Primitives.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Dynamic.Runtime.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Formats.Asn1.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Globalization.Calendars.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Globalization.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Globalization.Extensions.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.IO.Compression.Brotli.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.IO.Compression.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.IO.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.IO.FileSystem.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.IO.FileSystem.DriveInfo.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.IO.IsolatedStorage.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.IO.Packaging.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.IO.Pipes.AccessControl.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.IO.Pipes.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Linq.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Linq.Expressions.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Linq.Parallel.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Linq.Queryable.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Memory.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Net.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Net.Http.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Net.Http.Json.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Net.HttpListener.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Net.Mail.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Net.NameResolution.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Net.NetworkInformation.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Net.Ping.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Net.Primitives.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Net.Requests.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Net.Security.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Net.ServicePoint.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Net.Sockets.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Net.WebClient.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Net.WebProxy.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Net.WebSockets.Client.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Net.WebSockets.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Numerics.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.ObjectModel.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Reflection.DispatchProxy.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Reflection.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Reflection.Emit.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Reflection.Extensions.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Reflection.Metadata.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Reflection.Primitives.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Reflection.TypeExtensions.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Resources.Extensions.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Resources.Reader.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Resources.Writer.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.VisualC.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Runtime.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Runtime.Handles.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Runtime.Intrinsics.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Runtime.Loader.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Runtime.Numerics.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Security.AccessControl.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Security.Claims.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Security.Cryptography.Cng.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Security.Cryptography.Csp.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Security.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Security.Permissions.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Security.Principal.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Security.SecureString.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.ServiceProcess.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Text.Encoding.CodePages.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Text.Encoding.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Text.Encodings.Web.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Text.Json.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Threading.AccessControl.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Threading.Channels.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Threading.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Threading.Overlapped.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Threading.Tasks.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Threading.Thread.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Threading.ThreadPool.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Threading.Timer.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Transactions.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Transactions.Local.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.ValueTuple.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Web.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Web.HttpUtility.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Windows.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Windows.Extensions.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Windows.Forms.Design.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Windows.Forms.Design.Editors.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Windows.Forms.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Windows.Forms.Primitives.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Xml.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Xml.Linq.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Xml.Serialization.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Xml.XDocument.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Xml.XmlDocument.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Xml.XmlSerializer.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Xml.XPath.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Xml.XPath.XDocument.dll"
/reference:"C:\Users\Влади\.nuget\packages\validation\2.4.15\lib\netstandard1.3\Validation.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\WindowsBase.dll"
/debug-
/debug:portable
/filealign:512
/optimize+
/out:obj\Release\net5.0-windows\win-x64\***.dll
/refout:obj\Release\net5.0-windows\win-x64\ref\***.dll
/resource:obj\Release\net5.0-windows\win-x64\***.MainForm.resources
/resource:obj\Release\net5.0-windows\win-x64\***.PaletteForm.resources
/resource:obj\Release\net5.0-windows\win-x64\***.PreviewForm.resources
/resource:obj\Release\net5.0-windows\win-x64\***.Properties.Resources.resources
/target:winexe
/warnaserror-
/utf8output
/deterministic+
/langversion:9.0
/analyzerconfig:obj\Release\net5.0-windows\win-x64\***.GeneratedMSBuildEditorConfig.editorconfig
/analyzerconfig:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\analyzers\build\config\AnalysisLevel_5_Default.editorconfig"
/analyzer:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\..\analyzers\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.NetAnalyzers.dll"
/analyzer:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\..\analyzers\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers.dll" MainForm.cs MainForm.Designer.cs MainLib.cs PaletteForm.cs PaletteForm.Designer.cs PreviewForm.cs PreviewForm.Designer.cs Program.cs Properties\Resources.Designer.cs "obj\Release\net5.0-windows\win-x64\.NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs" obj\Release\net5.0-windows\win-x64\***.AssemblyInfo.cs
/warnaserror+:NU1605
```

Project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    <NeutralLanguage>ru-RU</NeutralLanguage>
    <Version>2.0.0.1</Version>
    <Authors>***</Authors>
    <Company>***</Company>
    <Product>***</Product>
    <Description>***</Description>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="PInvoke.User32" Version="0.7.78" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="Properties\Resources.Designer.cs">
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Resources.resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Properties\Resources.resx">
      <Generator>PublicResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Resources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Publishing profile configurations:

1. OK.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121. 
-->
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
    <Platform>Any CPU</Platform>
    <PublishDir>bin\publish\</PublishDir>
    <PublishProtocol>FileSystem</PublishProtocol>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
    <PublishSingleFile>True</PublishSingleFile>
    <PublishReadyToRun>False</PublishReadyToRun>
    <TrimMode>CopyUsed</TrimMode>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

2. OK.

```
...
    <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
    <PublishSingleFile>False</PublishSingleFile>
...
```

3. Not OK.

```
...
    <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
    <PublishSingleFile>True</PublishSingleFile>
...
```

Comment: Did you face any msbuild errors when you publish your project?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74811732/90475