# Could not find GeneratedMSBuildEditorConfig.editorconfig during React Native for Windows setup

Tags: reactjs, react-native, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, react-native-windows

I am trying to set up my first React Native for Windows project. I followed the steps in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dev-environment/javascript/react-native-for-windows) to install React Native for Windows. I navigated to the location I wanted my new project to be and then used the command

`npx react-native init ProjectName`

Then I navigated to the new folder ProjectName and used the command

`npx react-native-windows-init --language cs --overwrite`

After all that finished, I located the Visual Studio solution found inside ProjectName/windows and opened it in Visual Studio 2022. I set it to Debug x64 and tried to run the solution. However, I got the following error:

`Could not find a part of the path '[PATH]\ProjectName\node_modules\react-native-windows\Microsoft.ReactNative.Managed.CodeGen\build\x64\Debug\Microsoft.ReactNative.Managed.CodeGen\netcoreapp3.1\win-x64\Microsoft.ReactNative.Managed.CodeGen.GeneratedMSBuildEditorConfig.editorconfig'.`

I checked the location indicated, and the .editorconfig file is there, so I don't know why it can't find it, much less what the file is or why it is needed. I ran a search on the project folder and the only reference to this file I could find was in an FileListAbsolute.txt file, so I don't even know where Visual Studio is getting a reference to it. If I do a clean and rebuild on the solution, the build finishes successfully. But if I try to build the solution following that rebuild, or if I simply try to run the solution (regardless of whether I cleaned the solution first), I always get the above error. I've tried searching online for the error, but nothing I find ever has anything to do with my problem.

Why am I getting this error, and how do I resolve it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74811732/90475

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I think, this has to do with VS 2022 only supporting .NET v6+.

So I **reinstalled VS 2019**, opened the solution in there, set it to x64 and it rebuilt just fine.

Then I could start the project with `yarn windows` or `react-native run-windows` respectively.